# Relationship among Google Maps Api Services, KML files and Apple's KMLViewer

Tags: iphone, google-maps-api-3, kml

First I need to Google map api, to find the route between 2 points and output it.
I only see the directions request output in json and xml output. I don't see kml.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json  this works!

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/kml    this does not work!

Apple's KMLViewer takes a KML files and plot the route in color as overlay ontop of the google map.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html

I am planning to use Apple's KMLViewer as display on Iphone. But it needs KML files.

However, Google Map api do Not output KML files.

How should I approach this?

Comment: Have you read the [ReadMe.txt file](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KMLViewer/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010046-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_9) in the KMLViewer project?  Doesn't the `Add &output=kml to the end of the url` part work?

Comment: Nope, http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?  {
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}   but if try kml, http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/kml?    404. That’s an error.
The requested URL /maps/api/directions/kml was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

Comment: Make sure you follow the steps in that ReadMe file exactly.  Then you get a url like this: `http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=451+University+Avenue,+Palo+Alto,+CA+94301&daddr=1+Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino,+CA+95014&output=kml`

Comment: OK, how come that file kml from your example is empty? I download that kml file, there's nothing inside.

Comment: Somehow a space got between `&da` and `ddr`.  Anyway, follow those steps exactly.  Try [this](http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=451+University+Avenue,+Palo+Alto,+CA+94301&da‌​ddr=1+Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino,+CA+95014&output=kml)

Comment: Nice!  how would it be if above in longitudue, lattitude Coordinate points for saddr and daddr?

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches - You can use the unofficial &output=kml trick that Apple documents OR you can use the Web Service APIs and skip the whole KML bit.

Technically. you could the JSON or XML output you've mentioned to build your own KML file and load that into the KMLViewer but I think that's a kind of roundabout way to solve the problem.

The specific output you'll care most about in the JSON / XML you get from Google is probably the polyline.points element which includes an encoded polyline.  The algorithm to decode that string is available [here](http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/GoogleMaps/EncodePolyline/) with a few sample implementations.  You can easily use those decoded points into latitude / longitude points to build a [MKPolyline](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolyline_class/Reference/Reference.html) objects for each leg of the route, or just use the overview polyline from the API to get a rough approximation of the directions.  The build-your-own-KML route would use [linestring](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#linestring) elements in a KML file for each leg of the route.